# Regex to deal with punctuation and text improvement

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to avoid bad behavior on our app, and it needs me to clean some string from bad usage.

Let's says I have this string

```
str = "This is a very bad BEHAVIOR !!!Don't you think So ????";
```

I need to apply 3 rules :
- no shout mode (not all CAPS)
- Remove space before punctuation, and add one space after
- Remove all duplicate punctuation

So my string should be

```
str = "This is a very bad behavior! Don't you think so?"
```

I found on stackoverflow a sample code to add one space after punctuation :

```
str.replace(/[,.!?:;](?=\S)/g, '$& ');
```

But that does not help me to remove space before punctuation

Help would be really appreciate to find the right Regex

Comment: but what about "ask the FBI", "a != b", and "3.141592" ?

Comment: good point Dan, but this string correction is related to comment sent on a professional network.

For FBI, we could apply rules if more than 5 characters are uppercase only ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to work -

```
str.replace(/\s*([,.!?:;])[,.!?:;]*\s*/g,'$1 ').  //This removes all the punctuations
replace(/(?:^|[^a-z])([A-Z]+)(?:[^a-z]|$)/g,function(v){return v.toLowerCase();}). //Upper case to lower case
replace(/\s*$/,"") //Trimming the right end

OUTPUT:
"This is a very bad behavior! Don't you think So?"
```

**EDIT:**

Regarding the scenario where decimal points are used (like in case - `'This is 14.5 degree'`), using a Negative lookahead(like so - `(?!\d+)` ) should work.

For Example -

```
str = 'This is 14.5 degree'
str.replace(/\s*(?!\d+)([,.!?:;])[,.!?:;]*(?!\d+)\s*/g,'$1 ').  //This removes all the punctuations
replace(/(?:^|[^a-z])([A-Z]+)(?:[^a-z]|$)/g,function(v){return v.toLowerCase();}). //Upper case to lower case
replace(/\s*$/,"") //Trimming the right end

OUTPUT:
"This is 14.5 degree"
```

Comment: Works great for punctuation, but not that good for uppercase, cause it remove everything in uppercase including first letter of new sentences....

Comment: Can I apply this REGEX only if I Got [a-z] and [A-Z] between each punctuation ? 

str = str.replace(/\s*([,.!?:;])[,.!?:;]*\s*/g,'$1 ');


For exemple I need for str = 'This is 14.5 degree' to keep like it is and not to have 'This is 14. 5 degree'

Comment: @Toucouleur Check the edit. Regarding the case conversions, I am changing only those chars that are all in uppercase.

Comment: Thanks for this big help Kamehameha (DZ ?)

Comment: @Toucouleur Sure, glad to help!(Yep, :) DBZ)